# Realocar linha para um determinada posição de outra linha

Tags: script

#### Situação

Estava montando um ***script*** na qual eu sabia que deveria ter 17 campos, mas ainda não sabia com estes de chamariam, apos fui os definindo nos comentários, de tal forma que ficou desta forma :

```
// ds_ind_exig_iss
// ds_ind_exig_icms
// ds_ind_exig_impressao_documento
// ds_ind_exig_utilizacao_documento
// ds_ind_exig_livro_movimento_combustivel
// ds_ind_exig_registro_veiculo
// ds_ind_exig_registro_inventario
// ds_ind_oper_escrituracao_contabil
// ds_ind_oper_iss
// ds_ind_oper_retencao_tributaria
// ds_ind_oper_icms
// ds_ind_oper_icms_st
// ds_ind_oper_antecipacao_tributaria
// ds_ind_oper_ipi
// ds_ind_oper_registro_inventario

$registro0030 = array();
$registro0030[] = 1;
$registro0030[] = 7;
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form'][''];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form'][''];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form'][''];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form'][''];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form'][''];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form'][''];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form'][''];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form'][''];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form'][''];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form'][''];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form'][''];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form'][''];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form'][''];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form'][''];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form'][''];
```

#### Duvida

Como realocar o campos dos comentários para cada `['']` respectivamente, tendo em vista que seguem uma sequencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução que desenvolvi foi por ***REGEX***

#### Ajuste

```
{1} ds_ind_exig_iss
{2} ds_ind_exig_icms
{3} ds_ind_exig_impressao_documento
{4} ds_ind_exig_utilizacao_documento
{5} ds_ind_exig_livro_movimento_combustivel
{6} ds_ind_exig_registro_veiculo
{7} ds_ind_exig_registro_inventario
{8} ds_ind_oper_escrituracao_contabil
{9} ds_ind_oper_iss
{10} ds_ind_oper_retencao_tributaria
{11} ds_ind_oper_icms
{12} ds_ind_oper_icms_st
{13} ds_ind_oper_antecipacao_tributaria
{14} ds_ind_oper_ipi
{15} ds_ind_oper_registro_inventario

$registro0030 = array();
$registro0030[] = 1;
$registro0030[] = 7;
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['{1}'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['{2}'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['{3}'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['{4}'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['{5}'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['{6}'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['{7}'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['{8}'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['{9}'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['{10}'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['{11}'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['{12}'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['{13}'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['{14}'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['{15}'];
```

#### Regex

```
pattern : ^(\{\d+\}) (.*)\n([^%]+)(^.*)\1(.*\n)
replace : $3$4$2$5
```

#### Resultado

```
$registro0030 = array();
$registro0030[] = 1;
$registro0030[] = 7;
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['ds_ind_exig_iss'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['ds_ind_exig_icms'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['ds_ind_exig_impressao_documento'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['ds_ind_exig_utilizacao_documento'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['ds_ind_exig_livro_movimento_combustivel'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['ds_ind_exig_registro_veiculo'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['ds_ind_exig_registro_inventario'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['ds_ind_oper_escrituracao_contabil'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['ds_ind_oper_iss'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['ds_ind_oper_retencao_tributaria'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['ds_ind_oper_icms'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['ds_ind_oper_icms_st'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['ds_ind_oper_antecipacao_tributaria'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['ds_ind_oper_ipi'];
$registro0030[] = $this->dados['form']['ds_ind_oper_registro_inventario'];
```

#### Problemas

Como se trata de *REGEX* e um busca especifica, foi necessário executar 15 vezes o processo.
No meu caso como usei *Sublime* foi necessário clicar 15 vezes em `replace`.

Answer (score 1):

Usando `vim` (supondo que o `vim` esteja instalado e tenha suporte para Perl, como é usual)

```
:perldo if (m!// (.*)!){ push(@a,$1)};
:perldo s/''/"'".shift(@a)."'"/e
```

- 1 guarda no vector @a os valores começados por `// ....`
- 2 substitui cada `''`port cada um dos valores guardados